# Laravel - Unique rules validation - getMessages does not exist

Tags: validation, laravel, unique

I have a simple quiz app I'm writing where there is a series of challenges (Easy, Medium, Hard), each with their own questions.

The questions to be added should be unique.

I have the following code to "store" the data

```
$v = ChallengeQuests::validate(Input::all());

        if ( $v->passes() ) {
            print 'validate passed';
            $record = ChallengeQuests::create(array(
                'challenge_id'=> (int) Input::get('challenge_id'),
                'question_id'=> (int) Input::get('question_id')
            ));
            $record->save();
            return redirect()->to($url['redirects_to']);
        } else {
            print 'error';
            print_r($v->getMessages());
            return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($v->getMessages());
        }
```

In my model I have a validation method

```
// model
class ChallengeQuests extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'challengequests';
    protected $fillable=[
        'challenge_id',
        'question_id'
    ];

    public static function validate($input) {
        $rules = array(
            'challenge_id' => 'Required|Integer',
            'question_id' => 'Required|Integer|Unique:questions,id'
        );

        return Validator::make($input, $rules);
    }
}
```

But when I run my code, Laravel complains

```
BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 3016:
Method [getMessages] does not exist.
```

I'm wanting it so that the question_id is unique.

What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I am using:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
```

---

Stack trace:

```
BadMethodCallException in Validator.php line 3016:
Method [getMessages] does not exist.
in Validator.php line 3016
at Validator->__call('getMessages', array()) in ChallengeQuestionsController.php line 78
at ChallengeQuestionsController->store(object(Request))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ChallengeQuestionsController), 'store'), array(object(Request))) in Controller.php line 80
at Controller->callAction('store', array(object(Request))) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 146
at ControllerDispatcher->call(object(ChallengeQuestionsController), object(Route), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 94
at ControllerDispatcher->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in ControllerDispatcher.php line 96
at ControllerDispatcher->callWithinStack(object(ChallengeQuestionsController), object(Route), object(Request), 'store') in ControllerDispatcher.php line 54
at ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(object(Route), object(Request), 'App\Http\Controllers\ChallengeQuestionsController', 'store') in Route.php line 174
at Route->runController(object(Request)) in Route.php line 140
at Route->run(object(Request)) in Router.php line 724
at Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 726
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 699
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 246
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 52
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 132
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 99
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 53
at require_once('/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/laravel/scquiz/public/index.php') in server.php line 21
```

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace of the error.

Comment: Added stack trace as requested

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct method used to get the validation messages is not `getMessages()` it's `messages()`, so your code should look like this:

```php
return Redirect::to('/')->withErrors($v->messages());
```

Also if you're using Laravel 5, you might want to look into using [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#form-request-validation) which does the same thing you're trying to achieve but in a nicer way, and handles the validation on a different layer, taking care of passing the errors and page redirection for you.

---

By using a Form Request in your case, the controller method would be reduced to this:

```
public function store(ChallangeQuestsFormRequest $request)
{
    ChallengeQuests::create($request->only('challenge_id', 'question_id'));

    return redirect()->to($url['redirects_to']);
}
```

Since the rules and validation as well as redirection in case of an error, would be handled by the `ChallangeQuestsFormRequest` class. Also, using `create` to create a model entry will automatically save the entry, so there's no need to use `save` on the result of `create`.

Comment: Your solution works and I was able to raw output the messages via `print_r`.   I think Form Request Validation might be a bit much for me as I'm still learning Laravel.    I haven't been able to get the page to render the error messages, but I think I can solve this via a Flash message.

Comment: Form Request are not that complicated, they're just a class that you inject into the controller method as a parameter (like shown in my answer) and which contains the rules and handles validation for you. If the validation passes the controller method code is executed, if it fails it redirects back to your form with the errors nicely added into an {{ $errors }} variable as an array for you to display in the view. If you have time I would suggest you at least read the documentation I linked to, since it's only a few paragraphs and you might get the hang of it from the beginning.

Comment: Also as a side note, Laravel comes with a nice helper function named `dump`, which is like `print_r` but it formats nicely the output with correct indentation and colors.

Comment: Thanks for your help